# how to have successful deploy in AWS pipline with artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifacts, aws-codecommit

When I try to deploy my project with pipleline, some times I am getting below failer. 
Can you advice me what is wrong?

[image]

Action execution failed due:

```
Action execution failed
ChangeSet [abc-changeset] does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ChangeSetNotFound; Request ID: f49ef4e7-6971-4ea1-9467-05c2213c7bc4)
```

and after press retry problem will solve. would you mind help me to fix it?
[image]

my buildspec.yml is as below:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Install source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - export BUCKET=abc_bucket
      - echo copy file to S3 bucket...
      - aws s3 cp openapi.yml s3://abc_bucket/openapi.yml
      - echo packaging files by using cloudformation...
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yml
    - outputtemplate.yml
```

Comment: Any idea guys regarding this issue?

Comment: the pipeline trigger automatically when new commit accord?

Comment: @AmitBaranes: yes it is triggering automatically

Comment: Can you share the triggers as well?

Comment: @AmitBaranes: what triggers? sorry, I didn't get u.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are noticing is because both the Actions 'Create or Replace Change Set' and 'Execute Change Set' have been added to the same Action Group in the stage 'Deploy' which is creating a race-condition between change set creation and execution. To fix the issue, please create a new Action group and add the 'execute-changeset' to that new Action group.

Comment: @shariqmases: Do u mind add an example or reference link? I know how to create a new action group but I am not sure regarding the second part for adding a execute-changeset

Comment: 'execute-change...' action is already there in your screenshot :) What I mean with my response is to break the 2 actions (1. Deploy, 2. execute-changeset) in to two action groups. This way they will run in sequence and not in parallel.

Comment: super, I also can see it but I don't know how and when it creates, I already provided my buildspec.yml. I am not sure where it come from.

Answer (score 0):

if anybody is having this issue yet, just add "runOrder" to the action, 1 for replace o create changeset and 2 for execute changeSet

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you where should I add runOrder exactly?